# R: Creating a sequence substracting and adding a number into a single list (or vector)

Tags: r

I want to create a sequence from 1 to 7, substracting and adding .25 to each number. So, 14 elements in total in a single object.

I thought this would do the trick:

```
 1:7 + c(-.25, .25)
```

But I got an error because the "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length". Basically because that line doesn't tell R that I want to add and substract 0.25 to *each* number.
I tried using `sapply` and kinda worked:

```
sapply(1:7,FUN=function(x)c(x-.25,x+.25))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,] 0.75 1.75 2.75 3.75 4.75 5.75 6.75
[2,] 1.25 2.25 3.25 4.25 5.25 6.25 7.25
```

But it creates two lists and I need one. So I finally tried with a loop and it worked:

```
nums = NULL
for (i in 1:7){
  min = i-0.25
  max = i+0.25
  nums = cbind(nums,min,max)
}
nums = as.numeric(nums)
nums
[1] 0.75 1.25 1.75 2.25 2.75 3.25 3.75 4.25 4.75 5.25 5.75 6.25 6.75 7.25
```

My questions for you guys is, do you know of a better/shorter way to achieve the same result?

Thank you!

Comment: A matrix is a vector with `dim` attributes.  you can just do `c(sapply(1:7,FUN=function(x)c(x-.25,x+.25)))`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do it in a different order, like this:

```r
c(1:7 - 0.25, 1:7 + 0.25) 

#>  [1] 0.75 1.75 2.75 3.75 4.75 5.75 6.75 1.25 2.25 3.25 4.25 5.25 6.25 7.25
```

If you need it sorted just wrap it in sort()

<sup>Created on 2020-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `matrix` is a `vector` with `dim` attributes.  So, we could change to a vector with `c` that drops the attributes from the `matrix`

```
c(sapply(1:7,FUN=function(x)c(x-.25,x+.25)))
#[1] 0.75 1.25 1.75 2.25 2.75 3.25 3.75 4.25 4.75 5.25 5.75 6.25 6.75 7.25
```

---

Or make the lengths same with `rep` and then `+`

```
1:7 + rep(c(-.25, .25), 7)
```